# JQ/JS gallary slider, set different transistions

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Currently I am using the RefineSlide: http://alexdunphy.github.io/refineslide/

But I am not familiair with jquery/javascript. There are some transistions to choose from ('custom', random', 'cubeH', 'cubeV', 'fade', 'sliceH', 'sliceV', 'slideH', 'slideV', 'scale', 'blockScale', 'kaleidoscope', 'fan', 'blindH', 'blindV'):

For example I want this photo: 1/cubeH. 2/cubeV. 3/cubeH. 4/cubeV. 5/cubeH.

I know I can override the default settings when I call the script. As I said I am not familiar with J/JS, can I just make a CASE or use a if/else to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution for u by done some experiment,

In your jquery.refineslider.js, 
Line 655 to 658 replace the below code,

```
,random: function () { 
    if(flag_val == 1)
    {
             var dimension = $(this.RS.$slides).width() / 2;

            // If next slide is ahead in array
            if (this.forward) {
                this.cube(dimension, dimension, 0, 0, 90, 0, -90);
            } else {
                this.cube(dimension, -dimension, 0, 0, -90, 0, 90);
            }
            flag_val = 0;
    }
    else
    {
            var dimension = $(this.RS.$slides).height() / 2;

            // If next slide is ahead in array
            if (this.forward) {
                this.cube(dimension, 0, -dimension, 90, 0, -90, 0);
            } else {
                this.cube(dimension, 0, dimension, -90, 0, 90, 0);
            }
            flag_val = 1;               
    }

}
```

and also in top of ur js file below  `'use strict';`  declare variable

```
var flag_val = 1;
```

then set your transition as 'random' like  `transition : 'random',`  you can find this near line 15. thats it.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but tried this and it wont load any transistion.

Comment: Sorry for late reaction.. Prabu thank you very much! This works excellent, great job man!